# Emulate ESC Key in iOS Web App to toggle software keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, ios

This is on safari on an iOS device

I am using a Bluetooth HID RFID reader which acts like a hardware keyboard. So when you scan an RFID tag it will essentially type the CSN of the RFID into a text field my web app. Because this acts as hardware keyboard the software keyboard is constantly minimised.

My problem accures when I have an actaul text field which requires text input from the software keyboard.

When using a hardware keyboard, if you hit the ESC key, this toggles a viewable software keyboard.

When a text field is focused which requires real user text, I want the software KB to appear. Is there anything to show and hide the software keyboard?

Thanks!

Comment: how do you focus on the actual textfield? Could you share that piece of javascript code and also the relevant part of the HTML?

Comment: The focus is user interaction, when they click on a text field I trigger some JS which i will include above.